# How to calculate the distance between the centroid and the nearest point of the polygon in QGIS?

Tags: qgis

I have a shapefile as shown in the picture. I have estimated the centroid points of these polygons. How to estimate the distance between between the centroid and the minimum edge of the polygon in QGIS?
[image]

Answer (score 3):

You can easily be done in two steps:

1. Convert the polygons into lines (eg. using the `Polygons to lines` algorithm).
2. Run the `Join attributes by nearest` algorithm from the processing toolbox, using the centroids as input layer and the polygon borders as target layer.

This algorithm not only joins the attributes of the nearest polygon boundary to your centroids, it also outputs a **distance field** (as well as x/y fields for the nearest point on the boundary).

Comment: Thank you so much.

Comment: Glad I could help! Would you mind accepting the answer with the green checkbox?